# I'm not able to use spellcheck for textarea on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have Java web application deployed on Linux Tomcat server. When I am using
the application on windows IE8 browser, I am not able to see spellcheck . I am able to see spellcheck on IE10. Only on IE8 and before, I am not able to use spellcheck. On other browser, it's working fine.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: I am using JavaScriptSpellChecker using include.js. Its facing issue only   with IE8.For more than IE8 its working fine